# How to make longtable occupy its own standalone pages?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

There is some text and now I want to insert some pages containing a `longtable`. How can I achieve this goal?

To state my question clearly, I want

```
(Main text A)

-----------page break----------

longtable begins

-----------page break----------

longtable ends
(And although here is some space for text, but just leave it blank.)

-----------page break----------

(Main text A continues ...)
```

If I simply use `longtable` under Main text A, the table will adjoin it; if I add a `\newpage` under Main text A, there will be some unpleasant blank under Main text A -- furthermore, other floating objects still annoyingly break the long table.

So how to make `longtable` occupy its own standalone pages? Thank you for your help!

### EDIT

I've tried to put the long table in a standalone tex file and `\include{}` it in the expected place. It works fine partly: the `longtable` now can have its standalone pages perfectly, however, there's still some unpleasant blank under Main text A.

PS: I have to sleep now. Thanks for any possible help. I will check them tomorrow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [afterpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package and its command `\afterpage` may be your friend. As the command's name suggests, its main (only?) use is to defer the execution of some code block until after the end of the current page.

```
(Main text A)

\afterpage{% defer execution of the followng material until start of next page

longtable begins
--- page break ---
longtable continues
--- page break ---
longtable ends

\clearpage % omit if you want the material from the main text to continue on this page
} % end of afterpage material

(Main text A continues ...)
```

Comment: If the table is really big (or _long_:) it's probably better to stick it in a file and use `\afterpage{\clearpage\input{file}}` (the clearpage is just to stop any pending floats landing on the same page).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works like a charm! Thank you all :D